# psql: FATAL: sorry, too many clients already, HEROKU

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I have deployed a Rails app on Heroku since 2 years without trouble
Todays the app crash.

Rails log are:

```
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/pg-0.21.0/lib/pg.rb:56:in `initialize': FATAL:  sorry, too many clients already (PG::ConnectionBad)
FATAL:  sorry, too many clients already
```

My rails app is v5.2.0

I use Heroku with 2 dyno
The database is a postgres with "Hobby Dev".
I try:

- To upgrade the database but I got the same error

  ```
  heroku addons:create heroku-postgresql:standard-0 --follow DATABASE_URL --app locabri
  Creating heroku-postgresql:standard-0 on ⬢ xxxx... !
  ▸    An error was encountered when contacting the add-on partner to create heroku-postgresql:standard-0: The database you are attempting to follow was not found.
  ```
- to change DB_POOL in env variable
- heroku pg:info

  ```
  === DATABASE_URL
  Plan:                  Hobby-dev
  Status:                Available
  Connections:           0/20
  PG Version:            10.6
  Created:               2017-05-29 07:40 UTC
  Data Size:             138.8 MB
  Tables:                12
  Rows:                  5748/10000 (In compliance)
  Fork/Follow:           Unsupported
  Rollback:              Unsupported
  Continuous Protection: Off
  Region:                Europe
  Add-on:                postgresql-regular-79163
  ```

But nothing work.
I can't do anything on the database because I can't connect on it and and don't know how to restart it.
Thanks for your help or question

## EDIT

- heroku pg:killall
  doesnt work

## SOLUTION

I finally find the solution by changing the available dyno !

```
  heroku ps:scale web=0
  heroku ps:scale web=2
  heroku restart
```

Now I can check the "connexion leak"

Comment: Your application has a "connection leak", so this is an application bug. You'll have to find out why it keeps creating new database connections without ever closing old ones. Upgrading or modifying the database won't help. Raising `max_connections` is the wrong answer, because any limit will eventually be exceeded.

Comment: may be you can try to identify the opening connection from some hints here, https://stackoverflow.com/q/19814740/3230406 Try to find out why the connection might more than 20 concurrently.

Comment: I have the same issue today, unfortunately, none of the solutions above works.

Answer (score 1):

Recently I encountered a the same error message for one of my Python apps. I've reached out to Heroku and they acknowledged the error:

> FATAL: sorry, too many clients already

"It is generally triggered because the hobby tier databases are a shared resource which means that several databases will share computation and storage from a host. We monitor these regularly and always aim to run them with spare capacity but occasionally coincidental spikes in usage from neighboring databases can cause the host machine to have trouble. This is one of the reasons we don't endorse the hobby tier for use in production applications."

They suggested trying one of the following options:

1. Provision a new hobby database on the same plan and migrate the data over. This will spin up on a new database host which will mean that you no longer have the same noisy neighbors.
2. Upgrade to one of the professional plans

I've not tried the 1st option, but the second one solved my issue. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51246534/7547749) shows you how to do the migration step by step.