# Django+Channels+Heroku deployment with Daphne: Closing Postgre connections

Tags: django, postgresql, heroku, django-channels, daphne

My Django webapp deploys fine, however my db connections max out after a few queries to Postgres.

Here is my understanding of my problem:
Db connections to Postgres are opened for every query but not closed and this results is a db timeout once max connections is reached.

[Heroku documentation for this error](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/postgres-logs-errors#fatal-too-many-connections-for-role), but I think that whatever new number of connections are enabled through an upgrade, those connections will also max out fast. (Or am I wrong?)

pg:killall is not a solution to my problem. The solution must not be manual in this application.

I have used Heroku documentation for [Concurrency and DB connection in Django](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-concurrency-and-database-connections)

This [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19814740/13788660) is related but answers don't solve my problem

**Debug error**

```
FATAL: too many connections for role "DB_username"
```

**Error traceback failure point**

```
conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
```

**Running heroku pg:info --app appname in cmd**

```
=== DATABASE_URL
Plan:                  Hobby-dev
Status:                Available
Connections:           20/20      <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
PG Version:            12.4
Created:               2020-09-11 16:57 UTC
Data Size:             9.3 MB
Tables:                15
Rows:                  85/10000 (In compliance)
Fork/Follow:           Unsupported
Rollback:              Unsupported
Continuous Protection: Off
Add-on:                postgresql-infinite-00894
```

Here are the things I have tried:

1. setting dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age==0,...)
2. Using Pgbouncer to pool connections
3. Disabling server side cursors

**Settings.py**

```
# PRODUCTION SETTINGS
MIDDLEWARE.append('whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware')
DATABASE_URL = os.environ['DATABASE_URL']
DISABLE_SERVER_SIDE_CURSORS = True
SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY')
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'
#HEROKU SETTINGS
DATABASES['default'] = dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=0, ssl_require=True)
django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

*Installed pgbouncer buildpack*

**Procfile**

```
web: bin/start-pgbouncer
web: daphne appname.asgi:application --port $PORT --bind 0.0.0.0 -v2
chatworker: python manage.py runworker --settings=appname.settings -v2
```

This is the only Procfile that worked for me, I've seen people on other forums complain that you can't do 2 web dynos, this works for me, pgbouncer launches successfully at deployment, daphne works too. Using web and web2 crashes app. That being said I am open to trying any and all suggestions.

**asgi.py in case you're curious**

```
import os
import django
from channels.routing import get_default_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "Stonks.settings")
django.setup()
application = get_default_application()
```

The documentation around this is very confusing and other SO/code forums haven't suggested anything I haven't tried. Clarifying whether this is a Django code issue, Heroku config issue, or Daphne issue would be tremendously helpful as well.

**consumers.py sample**

```
class StatsConsumer(AsyncConsumer):
    """Creates your stats websocket for each connected user"""
    async def websocket_connect(self, event):
        """Connects to HTML and JS websocket for your stats"""
        await self.send({
            "type": "websocket.accept"
        })
        player = self.scope['user']
        player_bids_list = await self.get_bids(player)
        result_dict = await self.find_stats(player_bids_list)
        await self.send({
            "type": "websocket.send",
            "text": json.dumps(result_dict),
        })

    async def websocket_receive(self, event):
        """Is called when yourStats.html pings server for updated data"""
        player = self.scope['user']
        player_bids_list = await self.get_bids(player)
        result_dict = await self.find_stats(player_bids_list)
        await self.send({
            "type": "websocket.send",
            "text": json.dumps(result_dict),
        })

    async def websocket_disconnect(self, event):
        """Is called when websocket disconnects"""
        print("disconnected", event)

    @database_sync_to_async
    def get_profile(self, user):
        """fetches user profile funds asynchronously"""
        return Profile.objects.get(user=user).funds
    
    @database_sync_to_async
    def get_bids(self, user):
        """fetches the connected user's bids and returns all bids based on id, asynchronously"""
        userid = User.objects.get(username=user).id
        result = Bid.objects.filter(username_id=userid)
        returnlist = []
        for i in result:
            returnlist.append(i.amount)
        return returnlist
```

Comment: Do you decorate functions called from the consumers with `database_sync_to_async`? Please show your consumer code

Comment: Yes, (question updated with consumers.py). I used database_sync_to_async on all querying functions. The problem with db_connections even occurs for pages of the app that do not use websockets or trigger consumers.py